# How Async/Await handle multiple calls at same API end point from multiple user at same time

Tags: .net-core, async-await

I am working on an application where I have used `async`/`await` for every endpoint. My question here is how `async`/`await` handles multiple requests at the same time on the same API endpoint. For example, if I have an endpoint to save a user record and that endpoint has been hit by two different users at the same time, what will happen? Can somebody explain?

Here is the example code here I am registering a restaurant using `async`/`await`:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("RegisterRestaurant")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterRestaurant([FromBody] RegisterRequestDTO registerModel)
{
    var response = await _uow.UserRepository.RegisterRestaurant(new DTO.ResponseDTO.GenericResponseDTO<RegisterRequestDTO> { Data = registerModel });
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Everything is fine with this code. But what will happen if it is hit by multiple users from multiple places at same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question here is how async/await handles multiple requests at the same time on the same API endpoint. For example, if I have an endpoint to save a user record and that endpoint has been hit by two different users at the same time what will happen? Can somebody explain?

This actually has to do with how ASP.NET works, not `async`/`await`.

When new requests come in, ASP.NET takes a thread from the thread pool, constructs any necessary instances (e.g., an instance of your controller), and executes the handler for that request. So, each request is independent by default, unless your code explicitly uses `static` or singleton instances.

`async`/`await` do allow threads to return to the ASP.NET thread pool more quickly, but the core mechanism of ASP.NET handling requests is unchanged.

Comment: What is the case with static and singleton instances?

Comment: Those instances would be shared across requests.

Answer (score -1):

Which user will hit this action method first he will Register the restaurant and mean while second user will wait until the first user await completes.

Comment: Sorry but that was not my question